# Possible to use an ASP.NET control value in a Javascript file used in a Web Part?

Tags: javascript

When you are coding in an aspx page you can do something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var chkEnable = $get("<%= chkEnable.ClientID %>");
        alert(chkEnable);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form runat="server">
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnable" runat="server" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the only way I have found to use javascript in a web part is to use a ScriptLink that imports the file.  Example:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink5" runat="server" Name="myPorject/js/myCustomScript.js" Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="true"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnable" runat="server" />
```

Is there any way that I could reproduce the functionality from my first example in a web part?  Anything that I do must be able to be **installed entirely through a wsp** onto a system that I have no other access to.  Any solution must be implemented entirely through the wsp.

Comment: by wsp do you mean sandbox or farm solutions?

Comment: sorry, farm solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScriptLink is the recommended way if you're using a Farm solution. You can also add inline scripts to the WebPart (not the best way) or manually add your script tags to the WebPart.

Also take use of the Script-On-Demand (SOD) features that is available in SharePoint 2010: [Loading Script in SharePoint 2010 (Dallas Tester)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdev/loading-script-in-sharepoint-2010-dallas-tester).

To make the variable "dynamic"; add inline JavaScript code to your Web Part and just set the variable name/value there. Then use an external JavaScript file to host your logic.

Comment: Ok, so the external JS file will have access to that variable once I create it?  Do I need to load them in a specific order or anything?

Comment: If the variable is defined inline, then it will always be available before any external JS files. Use the SOD features to call your external script from inline code, so that you are sure that the file is loaded and ready.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing out to a literal using code behind? The can be a user control in a web part, which would be deployed as a wsp.